# Is dimethyl amine a sigma-donor or acceptor or pi-donor or acceptor?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I would argue that the $\ce{-NMe2}$ is a $\pi$-donor because the nitrogen atom has an unbound pair of electrons. At the same time it is a sigma-donor as the two methyl groups are good sigma donors. Is that correct?

As an example: N,N-dimethylaniline

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about -$\ce{NMe2}$, or -$\ce{NR2}$ in general, being a $\mathrm{\pi}$-donor ligands. References$^{1,2}$ do support this.

-$\ce{NMe2}$ is also a $\mathrm{\sigma}$-donor ligand, but not because of the methyl groups. Quoting ChemLibreTexts$^1$:

> (For) $\mathrm{\pi}$-donors, **in addition to donating electron density to a**
> **metal via a $\mathrm{\sigma}$-bond**, electrons may be provided to the
> metal via a $\mathrm{\pi}$-symmetry interaction. $\mathrm{\pi}$-donor
> ligands include -$\ce{X}$ (halide), -$\ce{NR2}$ amide, -$\ce{S^{2-}}$
> sulfide (S2–), -$\ce{O^{2-}}$ oxide, and -$\ce{OR}$.

#### References

1. [ChemLibreTexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Principles_of_Inorganic_Chemistry_II_(Nocera)/01%3A_Chapters/1.11%3A_Frontier_molecular_orbitals_of_-donor_-donor_and_-acceptor_ligands)
2. [Lecture Notes](https://www.chem.uci.edu/%7Elawm/11-25.pdf#:%7E:text=Examples%3A%20%E2%80%93%E2%80%93%E2%80%93%E2%80%93%E2%80%93%20Cl%2CBr%2CI%2COR%2CSR%2C,%E2%80%932%E2%80%932%E2%80%933%E2%80%93%20NR2%2CO%2CNR%2CN%20%CF%80-acceptorligands%28%CF%80-acidicligands%29areligandswithempty%CF%80%2Aorbitalsonthe%20donoratomthatcanacceptelectronsfromthemetal.) by Matt Law (and Alan Heyduk), Department of Chemistry, University of California, Irvine